# Notepad++ has stopped working

Tags: linux-mint, wine, snap

I am new to Linux, having previously been a Windows-only user. I installed Notepad++ two months ago and everything has been working fine. Then, out of the blue, today it has stopped working and will not longer open when I either click on the desktop icon or try to run it out of the terminal.

```
<UserName>@<MachineName>:~$ notepad-plus-plus 
Installing application.. 
Running hook '/snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/sommelier/hooks/pre-install' 
Starting application.. 
wine: cannot find L"/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/dosdevices
/z:/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus.exe"
```

- Note 1: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Notepad++ without success.
- Note 2: I installed Notepad++ both originally and today using Snap.

Can anyone please explain to me what is going on and how I can fix it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

My OS version:

- NAME=Linux Mint
- VERSION=20.3 (Una)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why it stop working, and i am sorry for you.
Note that there is plenty of replacement for this editor.
Personnaly, i use Geany.

https://alternativeto.net/software/notepad-plus-plus/?platform=linux